# How to save data between methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller that creates many images  from pdf(pdfBox).I save all picture to List .
**And I need to send one picture per view when I press the button. or enter value**

```
public class Pdf{
     public byte[] PDFCREATE(){
      byte[] pdf = ...;
        //Code for creating pdf using Itext
       return pdf;

    }
}

    public List<byte[]> getImage(byte[] pdf) throws Exception{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       List<byte> listImg = new List()<>;
        try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file)){
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
            {
                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page)
                ImageIO.write(bim, "png",baos);
                   listImg.add(baos)

            }
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to create pdf document - " + e);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
```

With view i **post**:

```
   public ResponseEntity<?> CreateFont(int pictureNumber ) {
        PDF pdf= new PDF();
PdfToImg pdfToImg = new PdfToImg();
List<byte []> fileBytes = pdfToImg.getImage(pdf.PDFCREATE());
byte[] encoded= Base64.encodeBase64(fileBytes.get(pictureNumber ));
String encodedString = new String(encoded);

            return new ResponseEntity<String>(
                    "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"  + encodedString + "' alt='' width='420' height='580'>",
                    HttpStatus.OK);
```

But here I have to create pdf each time. Is it possible to just save the values from getImage to the List?.And when the user enters value (pictureNumber) or press button each time not to create new pdf.And Instead of this take values from the List.**And create new List after refresh the page**I need to store somewhere List fileBytes,but where?

*Sorry for my English*

Comment: Do it properly - use a database. MySQL is free, so is MongoDB. If you ever scale up to more than one server then in-memory lists fail when your user is directed to the other server. Even if this is just a student toy app, learn how to do it properly. The experience will serve you well in your job interviews.

Comment: @ Andy Brown Just this information is needed only before updating the page.. In db there will be a lot of garbage (

Comment: @ Andy Brown Or just to rewrite the information in the BD each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might helps you:

```
private static Map<Integer, String> pictureMap = new HashMap<>();
private static PDF pdf;

public ResponseEntity<?> CreateFont(int pictureNumber) {
    if(pictureMap.containsKey(pictureNumber))
        return response(pictureMap.get(pictureNumber));
    if(pdf == null)
        pdf = new PDF();
    PdfToImg pdfToImg = new PdfToImg();
    List<byte[]> fileBytes = pdfToImg.getImage(pdf.PDFCREATE());
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(fileBytes.get(pictureNumber));
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    pictureMap.put(pictureNumber, encodedString);

    return response(encodedString);
}


private ResponseEntity response(String encodedString){
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(
        "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," + encodedString + "' alt='' width='420' height='580'>",
        HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it called for every post : PDF pdf = new PDF(); ?

Comment: @crazy_deviL at the top of method it will check if encodedString computed before and stored in map it will retrieve data and do not compute `PDF pdf = new PDF();` again

Comment: @SparaBut at first the pictureNumber will not be in Map, it will be saved only after the user sends the data. And every time he sends 0.1.2 ... 100. And all this time all classes will be called (

Comment: Aha `PDF pdf = new PDF();` is always same for all pictureNumbers? You can make it static. I will update my answer to cover that for you

Comment: @crazy_deviL now please check my answer

Comment: @SparaBut Thanks, and how to update static, when reloading the page?

Comment: @crazy_deviL why do you want to create the pdf again on page reload? maybe if I know the reason I could help you to make better decision

Comment: @SparaBut It will be very difficult to explain what I am doing). My English is very bad .. If without a description of all the details: 1 The user enters the data, and the PDF is created based on their data, 2. A picture of the first page of their PDF appears (pdf box)

Comment: 3. If the pdf has more pages than one, the user can switch pages with arrows (<- ->). And that's why I wrote my problem, because of switching between arrows. 4. When the user refreshes the page, all data is erased (including static)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185225/discussion-between-spara-and-crazy-devil).

Comment: When user reload page it should call another rest request. you can set `pdf = null` there.